# Change WooCommerce checkout order notes placeholder and label based on product Ids

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I am trying to rename the Order Notes label and placeholder based on product ID:s (array). But for some reason, this doesn't work. The text remains as is no matter what product that's in the cart and I'm getting an argument error.

Here is my customized code based on an existing answer code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'rename_order_notes_based_on_product', 10, 2 );
function rename_order_notes_based_on_product( $fields, $cart ) {
    $product_ids = array(11, 18);
    $found_ids = array();

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        foreach( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
            if ( in_array( $product_id, array( $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id'] ) ) ) {
                $found_ids[$product_id] = $product_id;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if ( count( $found_ids ) === count( $product_ids ) ) {
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Placeholder text here';
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Label text here';
    }
    else {

        $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Placeholder text here';
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Label text here';
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code, try the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'rename_order_notes_based_on_product' );
function rename_order_notes_based_on_product( $fields ) {
    $targeted_ids = array(11, 18); // Here set your targeted product Ids
    $found        = false; // Initializing

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( array_intersect( $targeted_ids, array( $item['product_id'], $item['variation_id'] ) ) ) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if ( $found ) {
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Placeholder text here (found)';
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Label text here (found)';
    } else {
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Placeholder text here (Not found)';
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Label text here (Not found)';
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should better work.

---

Or if you want to change order notes field placeholder and label **only if all targeted product Ids are in cart**, use the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'rename_order_notes_based_on_product' );
function rename_order_notes_based_on_product( $fields ) {
    $targeted_ids = array(11, 18); // Here set your targeted product Ids
    $found_ids    = array(); // Initializing

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( array_intersect( $targeted_ids, array( $item['product_id'], $item['variation_id'] ) ) ) {
            
            $found_ids[$item['data']->get_id()] = $item['data']->get_id();
        }
    }
    
    if ( count($found_ids) === count($targeted_ids) ) {
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Placeholder text here (match)';
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Label text here (match)';
    } else {
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Placeholder text here (Not match)';
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Label text here (Not match)';
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work too.