# Set a default value to a checkout field based on product ID in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, cart

I am hiding the `billing_email` field and have set a default value for this field which is a specific email address.

The code I inserted in the functions.php is the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'default_values_checkout_fields' );
  function default_values_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    // You can use this for postcode, address, company, first name, last name and such. 
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['placeholder'] = 'mymail@hotmail.hr';
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['autocomplete'] = 'mymail@hotmail.fr';
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['default'] = 'mymail@hotmail.fr';
    return $fields;
}
```

I actually want to have a different email set as default based on the product that is being bought. (The already cart only allows one product).

Can these values be set with a condition as shown in the following snippet the following?

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'default_values_checkout_fields' );
function default_values_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    // You can use this for postcode, address, company, first name, last name and such. 

    if $product_id === 17 {
        $fields['billing']['billing_email']['placeholder'] = 'mymail@hotmail.hr';
        $fields['billing']['billing_email']['autocomplete'] = 'mymail@hotmail.fr';
        $fields['billing']['billing_email']['default'] = 'mymail@hotmail.fr';
                 return $fields;
          }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the cart items via `WC()->cart->get_cart(),` then you can apply the conditions, if the product ID is present

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    // Set your targeted product ID(s)
    $targeted_ids = array( 17, 30 );
    
    // Initializing
    $found = false;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( array_intersect( $targeted_ids, array( $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id'] ) ) ) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // True
    if ( $found ) {
        // You can use this for postcode, address, company, first name, last name and such. 
        $fields['billing']['billing_email']['placeholder'] = 'mymail@hotmail.hr';
        $fields['billing']['billing_email']['autocomplete'] = 'mymail@hotmail.fr';
        $fields['billing']['billing_email']['default'] = 'mymail@hotmail.fr';
    }
    
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
```

---

Related: [Change WooCommerce checkout order notes placeholder and label based on product Ids](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67287709/11987538)